# First person singular "клáсть"

Tags: перевод, грамматика

According to starling.rinet.ru the first person singularis is: "кладý" for the verb: "клáсть" but the TA (Teaching Assistant) has stated that it is: "кладум". Is there some old form that is presently used in first person singular for this verb that you know of?

Starling result:

Infinitive: клáсть

Present/future tense

Singular    Plural

1 person    кладý   кладём

2 person    кладёшь кладёте

3 person    кладёт  кладýт

What the TA has presented it to be: "клáсть: кладум, кладёшь; клал, клала"
(everything but the first person singular seems to match up). My guess is that the clown got it right because he has induced a lot of typos and mistakes. I guess he is their best student.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Kладум* is an obvious typo, it is wrong, there's no such word, the correct form is *кладу*.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what TA stands for, but it's clearly a typo.

The Russian **-у** endings in the 1st person singular present descended from Proto-Slavic `-ǫ` (a nasal vowel, as in the French *Jean*), from an earlier `-on`. At no point did anything like "-um" exist.

Comment: Actually I wasn't first! I was typing when Yellow Sky's answer appeared. It says "21 mins ago" now on my answer, and "24 mins ago" on his.

Comment: ok I will be fair and revert. :)

Comment: TA stands for "teaching assistant".